# ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED socket.io 1.4.5

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

io version 1.4.5 in server and client both side i did update socket version 0.9.16 to 1.4.5 after update in server side its working perfect but in client side am not able to connect socket every time i get this error

this is error from client side code

> GET http://000.000.000.000:9008/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LNbIgGT net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

this is my connection code in client side

```
var local = "http://" + document.location.host + ":9008";
    var remote = 'http://000.000.000.000:9008/';
    socket = io.connect(!!local ? local : remote);
    socket.on("connect", function () {
    console.log("connectedddd");                
    });
```

and this is socket.io js file link

```
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.5.js"></script>
```

so please anyone have solution so please help me i need it quickly

Comment: Since you mentioned an upgrade to 1.4.5 and while you're waiting for an answer, spend some time building the [chat application](http://socket.io/get-started/chat/) and get that working. Then adapt your code. Also, try hard-coding the addresses. That 000 address looks wrong to me. Where is the remote, really? Try that address instead. Verify your server is setup to listen on port 9008 and that the port is open on the remote.

Comment: 000 is for demo and yes i use 9008 port for remote